# What happens if I install 2 plugins for the same Google Analytics tracking code?

Tags: google-analytics, wordpress, statistics, plugin, bounce-rate

If I install (on WordPress) 2 plugins for the same Google Analytics tracking code, is it possible that views, etc. are counted 2 times?

I am asking it because on the exact day where I have changed from "Google Analytics Dashboard for WP (GADWP)" and "Google Analytics for WordPress by MonsterInsights" to "GA Google Analytics" I got:

- Plus 80% bounce rate (see image)
- 1/2 views (see image)

Were they counting the views 2 times?

[image: Stats]